# Datepicker dateFormat is not loading properly

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to load my jQuery UI datepicker field with the FULL date shown. So I do the following:

```
$("#reminderDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy" });
```

However, when the page first loads, the the date appears in default format mm/dd/yyy, but after I select another date it changes to full format. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever server side language you're using to output the value of that `<input>` element needs to format the date so that it matches the format you're using in the date picker. The datepicker won't auto-format the value that's originally set against the `<input>` element.